# Custom Ubuntu Live with LaTex and editor

Tags: latex

My Acer Aspire E5 Windows 10 computer is broken right now.  I can only boot into Ubuntu Live from this USB, and I fried my BIOS and I cannot boot from any other USB except this Linpus Lite bootable USB of Ubuntu 18.04.  I want to use Ubuntu Live to create another USB that has a custom Ubuntu Live with LaTeX (tex-live) and .tex editor (Tex Studio).  I don't know how to do that.  What are the steps?

Comment: If you can only boot from that single USB, then don't make changes to it. Spend your energy getting your hardware fixed instead of workarounds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

Comment: @user535733  I'm not trying change this USB, I want to make another one.  My computer has 3 USB ports.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a persistent live USB that stores all your session data and apps installed during the live session permanently. As in install any apps and download or save files onto the USB's storage. [This](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/) guide may help.

But I strongly recommend fixing you hardware as soon as possible as persistent USB treats your USB drive as a hard drive. This is not good in the long run as USB drives have limited read/write operations over their lifetime and this type of usage burns through them very quickly.